# Assigning new autoincrement id to returned SQL result in Anorm

Tags: sql, scala, playframework-2.2, anorm

Near the bottom, insertedID is an Option[Long] representing the returned id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY from MySQL. I want to populate the field in the question object before returning it to the caller.

```
def update(question: Question): Question = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        val insertedId = SQL(
          """
          replace into question values (
            {id},
            {question_text},
            {date_created},
            {subject},
            {curriculum},
            {year},
            {question_type},
            {optional_image},
            {answer_key},
            {answer_1},
            {answer_2},
            {answer_3},
            {answer_4},
            {answer_5},
            {keywords}
          )
          """
        ).on(
          'id -> question.id,
          'question_text -> question.question_text,
          'date_created -> question.date_created,
          'subject -> question.subject,
          'curriculum -> question.curriculum,
          'year -> question.year,
          'question_type -> question.question_type,
          'optional_image -> question.optional_image,
          'answer_key -> question.answer_key,
          'answer_1 -> question.answer_1,
          'answer_2 -> question.answer_2,
          'answer_3 -> question.answer_3,
          'answer_4 -> question.answer_4,
          'answer_5 -> question.answer_5,
          'keywords -> question.keywords
        ).executeInsert()

        // question.id = insertedId  Reassignment to val?

        question

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Question a case class? You probably need to return this instead (as opposed to an instance of the same case class):

```
insertedId match {
  case Some(id) => question.copy(id = id)
  case _ => question 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wes this is extremely helpful, yes it is a case class and its amazing how far I got into this application without having to figure out that they are immutable! I have an additional problem I have been wrestling with just as much though, and that is that in the case class, 'id' is an Option[Int]. I have tried every map() approach from all of the documentation I've looked over, but I still 'dont get it' in terms of converting it into Option[Int] for question.copy.

Comment: Ah, Long to Int. Are you sure you don't want to just convert it to a Option[Long] so you can just return `question.copy(id=insertedId)` without the match? If not, you can do my code with `id=Some(id.toInt)`

Comment: Bingo. I had tried that before, but was mishandling the return value in the caller. And yeah I am going to go back to change the to Option[Long], but the number of places it needs to be changed with Anorm/Play is exhausting.